# ctypes: how to correctly update the pointers?

Tags: python, c, function, pointers, ctypes

I would like to use this c function from python with ctypes, here the c function:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "math.h"

void modwtj(double *Vin, int N, int j, int L, double *ht, double *gt, 
     double *Wout, double *Vout)
{

  int k, n, t;

  for (t = 0; t < N; t++) {
    k = t;
    Wout[t] = ht[0] * Vin[k];
    Vout[t] = gt[0] * Vin[k];
    for (n = 1; n < L; n++) {
      k -= (int) pow(2.0, (double) j - 1.0);
      if (k < 0) {
    k += N;
      }
      Wout[t] += ht[n] * Vin[k];
      Vout[t] += gt[n] * Vin[k];
    }
  } 

}
```

And here the python code, I initialize Wout and Vout for the ouput but I noticed that these are not changed by the modwtj function, how I correctly assign the output ?

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
lib = ctypes.CDLL('/import_modwt/libmodwtj.so')

Vin=data[0,:,0]
ht=np.asarray([-0.0075,-0.0233,0.0218]).astype(np.double)
gt=np.asarray([0.1629,0.5055,0.4461]).astype(np.double) 

N = int(600)
j = 1  # scale
coeff_length = int(3)  # filter length

Wout = np.random.rand(N,1).astype(np.double)
Vout = np.random.rand(N,1).astype(np.double)

array_type_a = ctypes.c_double * N
array_type_ht = ctypes.c_double * coeff_length
array_type_gt = ctypes.c_double * coeff_length
array_type_out = ctypes.c_double * N

lib.modwtj.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
                      ctypes.c_int,
                      ctypes.c_int,
                      ctypes.c_int,
                      ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
                      ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
                      ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
                      ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)]
 lib.modwtj.restype = None
 lib.modwtj(array_type_a(*Vin),
           ctypes.c_int(N),
           ctypes.c_int(j),
           ctypes.c_int(coeff_length),
           array_type_ht(*ht),
           array_type_gt(*gt),
           array_type_out(*Wout),
           array_type_out(*Vout))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `array_type_out(*Wout)`. That takes `Wout` and creates an `array_type_out` instance but **it copies the values** from `Wout`, so `Wout` and `array_type_out(*Wout)` will be independent (modifying one **won't impact** the other). 
The solution would be to construct the output *np* arrays (`Wout` and `Vout`) out of the data that has been modified by `lib.modwtj` (`array_type_out(*Wout)` and `array_type_out(*Vout)` that should have been saved into variables).

I prepared a "small" example.

*modwtj.c*:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#   define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define DLL_EXPORT
#endif


DLL_EXPORT void modwtj(const double *vIn, int n, int j, int l, const double *ht, const double *gt, double *wOut, double *vOut) {
    int batches = n / l, last = n % l, i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < batches; i++)
        for (int k = 0; k < l; k++)
        {
            wOut[i * l + k] = vIn[i * l + k] + ht[k] + j;
            vOut[i * l + k] = vIn[i * l + k] + gt[k] + j;
        }
    for (int k = 0; k < last; k++) {
        wOut[i * l + k] = vIn[i * l + k] + ht[k] + j;
        vOut[i * l + k] = vIn[i * l + k] + gt[k] + j;
    }
}
```

*code.py*:

```python
import sys
import ctypes
import numpy as np


modwtj_lib = ctypes.CDLL("libmodwtj.so")
modwtj_func = modwtj_lib.modwtj
modwtj_func.argtypes = [
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int,
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double),
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
]
modwtj_func.restype = None

data_array_dim = 10  # Size for v_in, w_out, v_out arrays
coeff_array_dim = 4  # Size for ht, gt arrays
scale = 1

double_data_array = ctypes.c_double * data_array_dim
double_coeff_array = ctypes.c_double * coeff_array_dim


def print_ctypes_array(array, array_name=None):
    print("{:s}en: {:d}:\n    {:s}".format(str(array_name) + " - l" if array_name else "L", len(array), ", ".join(["{:.3f}".format(item) for item in array])))


def print_ctypes_arrays(*arrays_data):
    print("\nPrinting ctypes arrays...")
    for array_data in arrays_data:
        array, array_name = array_data
        print_ctypes_array(array, name=array_name)

def print_np_array(array, array_name=None):
    print("{:s}{:s}".format(str(array_name) + ": " if array_name else "", repr(array)))


"""
def test_no_np():
    print("\n{:s}".format(test_no_np.__name__))
    v_in = double_data_array(*range(1, 1 + data_array_dim))
    ht = double_coeff_array(*(1,) * coeff_array_dim)
    gt = double_coeff_array(*(2,) * coeff_array_dim)
    w_out = double_data_array()
    v_out = double_data_array()
    print_ctypes_arrays((v_in, "v_in"), (ht, "ht"), (gt, "gt"), (w_out, "w_out"), (v_out, "v_out"))
    modwtj_func(v_in, data_array_dim, scale, coeff_array_dim, ht, gt, w_out, v_out)
    print_ctypes_arrays((w_out, "w_out"), (v_out, "v_out"))
"""


def test_np():
    print("\n{:s}".format(test_np.__name__))
    v_in_np = np.asarray(range(1, 1 + data_array_dim)).astype(np.double)
    ht_np = np.asarray([1] * coeff_array_dim).astype(np.double)
    gt_np = np.asarray([2] * coeff_array_dim).astype(np.double)
    w_out_np = np.asarray([0] * data_array_dim).astype(np.double)
    v_out_np = np.asarray([0] * data_array_dim).astype(np.double)

    v_in = double_data_array(*v_in_np)
    ht = double_coeff_array(*ht_np)
    gt = double_coeff_array(*gt_np)
    w_out = double_data_array(*w_out_np)

    print("TESTING arrays relation")
    print_np_array(v_out_np, array_name="v_out_np")
    v_out = double_data_array(*v_out_np)  # The data from v_out_np has been copied to v_out, so the 2 arrays are detached now, meaning that modifying one will not impact the other
    print_ctypes_array(v_out, array_name="v_out")
    v_out_np[1] = 3
    v_out[2] = 5
    print_np_array(v_out_np, array_name="v_out_np")
    print_ctypes_array(v_out, array_name="v_out")
    print("DONE testing")

    modwtj_func(v_in, data_array_dim, scale, coeff_array_dim, ht, gt, w_out, v_out)

    w_out_np = np.asarray(w_out).astype(np.double)
    v_out_np = np.asarray(v_out).astype(np.double)

    # Create the np arrays from modified data
    print_np_array(w_out_np, array_name="w_out_np")
    print_np_array(v_out_np, array_name="v_out_np")


def main():
    #test_no_np()
    test_np()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- *C*:

  - I modified the function, so that output array `${OUT_ARRAY}[i] = vIn[i]  + ${COEFF_ARRAY}[i] + j` (where `${COEFF_ARRAY}` is duplicated if shorter than `vIn`) for `${OUT_ARRAY}, ${COEFF_ARRAY}`:

    - `wOut, ht`
    - `vOut, gt`
- *Python*:

  - Adapted variable names to be [[Python]: PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) compliant
  - The code is long, but the lines that are strictly related to the problem are the the 2 right after `modwtj_func` call (in `test_np`)
  - A **more elegant** (and straightforward) **solution** would be to **use *np*'s *ctypes* interface** (that would operate on the *np* arrays directly), but my experience in that area is fairly limited

**Output**:

> ```
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051481025>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051481025>dir /b
> code.py
> modwtj.c
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051481025>cl /nologo modwtj.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:libmodwtj.so
> modwtj.c
>    Creating library libmodwtj.lib and object libmodwtj.exp
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051481025>dir /b
> code.py
> libmodwtj.exp
> libmodwtj.lib
> libmodwtj.so
> modwtj.c
> modwtj.obj
>
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051481025>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> test_np
> TESTING arrays relation
> v_out_np: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
> v_out - len: 10:
>     0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000
> v_out_np: array([0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
> v_out - len: 10:
>     0.000, 0.000, 5.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000
> DONE testing
> w_out_np: array([ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12.])
> v_out_np: array([ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.])
> ```